# Trying/ Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on HP EliteDesk puts monitor Display to sleep

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation, hp

I have a requirement to install Ubuntu 16.04 in HP EliteDesk 800-G3-TWR. The system runs fine till GNU GRUB Boot Menu. However, the monitor display goes to sleep on selecting any option: Install Ubuntu and  Try live from USB.

It must be noticed that for a second i am able to hear Ubuntu OS boot sound (of drums).

Few other findings are:

- Ubuntu 18.04 gets successfully installed.
- Tried in legacy and UEFI modes, but showing same behavior in any case.
- Also tried tweaking
  BIOS settings like disabling TPM, Secure Boot etc. but no use.

Comment: Try booting with nomodeset and also without quiet splash. When GRUB boot menu pops up press "e" key to change the entry and as stated before remove "quiet splash" and replace with "nomodeset". Let me know what happens, nomodeset should not load graphic drivers.

Comment: I did this. I get a blank ubuntu desktop screen with cursor only. No mouse click or commands work.

Comment: I am able to install ubuntu with quite splash and nomodeset parameters. It is being installed. *fingers crossed* and the installer crashed.

Comment: In my next attempt, i get successfully ubuntu installed. However, it never ges booted. I dont even go to the grub screen. After my system screen, i get a purple screen.

Comment: The purple screen is given by the "splash" parameter in GRUB entry, "quiet" prevent writing boot logs, if you remove both you'll see where your boot flow gets stuck.

Comment: This gives me ubuntu desktop screen with no icons/ bars, along with flickering error message "Sorry Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error"